# Small X in corner of home page, due to jquery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay

Having problems with a clients website, the site has separate jquery sections with a button in each that opens up another modal window.

This modal window has a close button in the top corner, this close button is appearing on page load and is positioned on the top right of the home page. Having problems removing this overlay to make it only be viewable in the modal window? Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the website?

Comment: Your question is lacking details. Impossible to answer without seeing code.

Comment: +1 To Matt, or at the very least provide some code and/or a live example at a place like jsfiddle.net

Comment: why didn't you put the close button inside the modal window?

Answer (score 2):

Your overlays need to be set initially to `display:none`.

Comment: display:none will remove the x altogether, even for the modal windows

Comment: If you put display none on the `.close` then yes, you are correct.  But, if you put it on the overlay it will not.  You do not want your overlay displayed by default.